# Java Client/Server don't communicate through Socket/ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I have a simple `socket`/`serversocket` example that I'm trying to get running, but both the client and the server hang when their `BufferedReader`s try to read. Here is the code for each:

**SERVER**

```
package picturePerfect;
--imports--

public class PictureServer implements Runnable{
static ServerSocket serverSocket;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2342);
    Thread firstSessionThread = new Thread(new PictureServer());
    firstSessionThread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String clientRequest = bufferedReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(clientRequest);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        printWriter.println("Sent from server!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

}

**CLIENT**

```
package picturePerfect;
--imports--

public class PictureClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 2342);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        printWriter.write("Sent from client!");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String response = bufferedReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

This is the barest I could simplify my code to. I have a sample program that I've been following, which seems nearly exactly the same. This is the sample server and client (that *does* work):

**SAMPLE SERVER**

```
--imports--

public class Server implements Runnable{
    static ServerSocket ss;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ss = new ServerSocket(3142);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Server());
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( true ) {
            Socket s = null;

            try {
                s = ss.accept();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                String operands = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(operands + " was received");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                pw.println(operands + " right back!");
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SAMPLE CLIENT**

```
--imports--

public class Server implements Runnable{
    static ServerSocket ss;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ss = new ServerSocket(3142);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Server());
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( true ) {
            Socket s = null;

            try {
                s = ss.accept();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                String operands = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(operands + " was received");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                pw.println(operands + " right back!");
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried putting the while loop into my server and moving my client and server to the default package, but neither helped. I also tried using `read()` instead of `readLine()`, and ending the printWriter's lines with `\r\n`, but was just as unsuccessful there.

Why does my code hang on `readLine()`, especially when the sample code doesn't?

Comment: If you're on Windows, check out TCPView here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx to monitor packets being sent/received by port/process. I used it when I made a server/client application in Java a couple of weeks ago and it was pretty handy to see if it was a display error or a network error.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty cool! I didn't end up needing it here, but it will be useful for the next project I do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `readline()` does is wait until it sees a new line character until it returns, hence readLine().

In your client, you do not write a new line. You use:

```
printWriter.write("Sent from client!");
```

Instead, write a newline character into the stream using println,

```
printWriter.println("Sent from client!");
```

Comment: Oh man. I feel like I need to go relearn my basics, haha. Thanks! Guess you just need another pair of eyes to look it over sometimes. :P

Answer (score 2):

Server expects to read line, so you need to add line separators after your massage. To do this instead of

```
printWriter.write("Sent from client!");
```

in client use

```
printWriter.println("Sent from client!");
//          ^^^^^^^
```

or

```
printWriter.write("Sent from client!"+System.lineSeparator());
printWriter.flush();
```

You will need to `flush` yourself because autoflush in PrintWriter works only for `println`, `printf`, or `format`, not for `write` method

Comment: Thank you! I guess you just have to have someone else see it sometimes, haha.

Comment: Story of most SO questions :) Anyway I am glad I could help.